# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mhash() in C:\xampp\htdocs\LiveContactsPHP\windowslivelogin.php on line 1516

Tags: php

Can anyone help me out. I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mhash() in C:\xampp\htdocs\LiveContactsPHP\windowslivelogin.php on line 1516

Comment: you can use: pack('H*', hash('md4', $str))

Answer (score 0):

> You need to compile PHP with the
>   --with-mhash[=DIR] parameter to enable this extension. DIR is the mhash
>   installation directory.

You have to install mhash library. [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mhash.requirements.php) are the instruction for same.

Comment: How i will install please help me out

Comment: @user784018: If you go with the posted http://www.php.net/manual/en/mhash.requirements.php link. Here is very clear instruction to install it

Comment: actually I downloaded mhash source code but there is lot of folders & files I did not understand how I will do.

Comment: actually I downloaded mhash source code but there is lot of folders & files I did not understand how I will do. –I hope you will give me reply as soon as posssible.                                              Thanks in advance.